# Why are all roles assigned to a user when using wp_insert_user()?

Tags: user-roles

I am working on a page within a WordPress multisite install.

I am using `wp_insert_user()` to add users. I need to do this programmatically.

The problem I have is with the roles.
Every time I create a user, *all* roles are added to this user.
It seems to happen both when I don't specify a role and when I specify only one role.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this the default behavior when adding new users?

Comment: can you show us your code? It's very difficult to diagnose code issues blind, edit your question to include it

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the user straight after they have been created. So yes, by default they get all then you update.

`wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'user_role_here') );`

The above should fix this issue.

Obviously changing the `$user_id` to your style of ID and also `user_role_here` to `editor` or alike.

Thanks,
Tom